# UML-RT Modeling Tool

Tags: uml

I'm looking for a modeling tool which supports UML-RT, but I'm not able to find any.
I already have MS Visio (2010), Power Designer (2008) and Rational Rose but it seems that non of them contains UML-RT features (like Capsule). any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IBM's Rational Software Architect, which is an Eclipse-based modelling environment, exists in a Real-Time Edition (RSARTE).

The company I work for is an IBM/Rational partner; feel free to contact us for further information (the web site is listed in my profile).

[RSA product home page](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/products/rsa/)

[RSARTE support portal](http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/Overview/Software/Rational/Rational_Software_Architect_RealTime_Edition)

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse with Papyrus component, explore the following link:
http://www.eclipse.org/papyrus/

Comment: After installing papyrus, you can get the UML-RT optional component installed - although it appears to be there by default in the nightly builds for Luna.

Comment: thank you @Blatorg for the hint,Does UML-RT will replace MARTE as what MARTE did(replaces SPT profile)?

Comment: @Melisa, No, UML-RT is not intended to replace MARTE. MARTE does provide additional information that can be useful when developing embedded or "real time" software (e.g., information specifying constraints of the system, a bit like SysML). I would hope that, in the future, UML-RT code generators would be able to use MARTE information and that, potentially, MARTE information could be used to define test systems - but we are not close to being there...

Comment: Just a quick note that there is now a  Papyrus for Real Time that implements UML-RT as a DSML on top of Papyrus.